# Initializing materialize elements in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, materialize, vuejs2

How can I initialize the Materializes' select or modal elements in Vue.js? When I add the following code in my document ready the elements do not work.

```html
<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal('open');
  $('select').material_select();
});

//Vue.js code here...   
 
</script>
```

Comment: Put this jQuery code into the `mounted()` hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and call this code in one of Vue's [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) (see [this diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) to find out where exactly they're executed), you'll probably want to use `mounted`.

But keep in mind this isn't really a bulletproof solution. Vue may manipulate the DOM in different ways later and as such isn't necessarily compatible with Materialize. The best solution in these cases is always to find a framework-specific implementation of the components you're trying to use, e.g. [Vue Material](https://vuematerial.github.io/).